# Cloudformation for redis parameter group

Tags: redis, aws-cloudformation

I want to create a cloudformation template to deploy a redis parameter group. The problem lies in the fact that each of my parameters looks like this:

```
{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "ParameterName": "activedefrag",
            "ParameterValue": "no",
            "Description": "Enabled active memory defragmentation",
            "Source": "user",
            "DataType": "string",
            "AllowedValues": "yes,no",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "MinimumEngineVersion": "4.0.9",
            "ChangeType": "immediate"
        },
        {
            "ParameterName": "active-defrag-cycle-max",
            "ParameterValue": "75",
            "Description": "Maximal effort for defrag in CPU percentage",
            "Source": "user",
            "DataType": "integer",
            "AllowedValues": "1-75",
            "IsModifiable": true,
            "MinimumEngineVersion": "4.0.9",
            "ChangeType": "immediate"
        }
}
```

Now I understand the basic format of the template but can't figure out how to pass in parameters as seen above.

Failing template:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Template to create a consul cluster",
  "Parameters": {
    "CacheParameterGroupFamily": {
      "Description": "The name of the cache parameter group family that this cache parameter group is compatible with.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "redis4.0",
      "AllowedValues": ["memcached1.4", "memcached1.5", "redis2.6", "redis2.8", "redis3.2", "redis4.0", "redis5.0"]
    },
    "ParameterGroupDescription": {
      "Description": "What this parameter group will be used for",
      "Type": "String"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "RedisParameterGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheParameterGroupFamily" : { "Ref": "CacheParameterGroupFamily" },
        "Description" : { "Ref": "ParameterGroupDescription" },
        "Properties" : {
            "Parameters": [{
                "ParameterName": "activedefrag",
                "ParameterValue": "no",
                "Description": "Enabled active memory defragmentation",
                "Source": "user",
                "DataType": "string",
                "AllowedValues": "yes,no",
                "IsModifiable": true,
                "MinimumEngineVersion": "4.0.9",
                "ChangeType": "immediate"
            }]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You need to incorporate those parameters into the `Parameters` section of the template, and change the syntax so that it conforms to the [Parameters format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#parameters-section-structure-properties).

[image]

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Template to create a consul cluster",
  "Parameters": {
    "CacheParameterGroupFamily": {
      "Description": "The name of the cache parameter group family that this cache parameter group is compatible with.",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "redis4.0",
      "AllowedValues": ["memcached1.4", "memcached1.5", "redis2.6", "redis2.8", "redis3.2", "redis4.0", "redis5.0"]
    },
    "ParameterGroupDescription": {
      "Description": "What this parameter group will be used for",
      "Type": "String"
    },
    "activedefrag": {
        "Description": "Enabled active memory defragmentation",
        "Type": "String",
        "AllowedValues": ["yes", "no"],
        "Default": "no"
    },
    "activedefragcyclemax": {
        "Description": "Maximal effort for defrag in CPU percentage",
        "Type": "Number",
        "Default": 75,
        "MinValue": 1,
        "MaxValue": 75
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "RedisParameterGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheParameterGroupFamily" : { "Ref": "CacheParameterGroupFamily" },
        "Description" : { "Ref": "ParameterGroupDescription" },
        "Properties" : {
            "activedefrag": {"Ref": "activedefrag"},
            "active-defrag-cycle-max": {"Ref": "activedefragcyclemax"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do I specify things in that parameter. For example: in parameter _activedefrag_, if I want to specify "Source" as "user". How would I do that?

Comment: All the parameters you specify in the `Parameters` section of the template will have to be entered by the user when you create the stack.